# How to configure search in two App servers in SharePoint 2019. Any good resources or suggestions?

Tags: 2019, sharepoint-search, upgrade-sharepoint

I have a farm with 2 app servers and 2 web servers. I am upgrading from SP 2016 to 2019. How do I configure Search service application for 2 app servers in SP 2019 using powershell? Also how do i have to upgrade the database for search service application. Any good resources or links would also work. Thank you.